# How to set a value of an ASP.NET TextBox value in the ASP.NET ViewState HiddenField

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET TextBox and its Text is set with JavaScript all of us know that if the page do a postback this Text will disappear because its not set from the server to hold its value on the ViewState HiddenField the ASP.NET Create for Saving the State of the ASP.NET Controls

so is there is a way officially created by the ASP.NET Team to manually set the value of the TextBox into the HiddenField or there is a trick with that on the other hand i don't need to write any server side code to Save the state of that value set from the Client Side

Regards

Comment: Actually, TextBox should persist value from client-side. Did you set `ReadOnly="true"` or `Enabled="false"` properties on TextBox?

Comment: A good Question would be. Is the TextBox value, setted with javascript being sent with the request? If positive you can get the value using this: Request.Form[textbox.UniqueID].

Answer (score 0):

so you have an asp text box and your code behind is not picking up its value?

you're close to answering your own question i think

if the value is set via javascript then its the same as if an end user just entered it
- its on the client, you just need to get it to the server

if viewstate is enabled on the text box 
and a postback is performed then it will be sent to the server
...so one of those things is not happening

i.e. you need to enable your viewstate on the textbox and/or initiate a postback